# esp32 install sdk

Tags: esp8266

I want to install a SDK that is available for the ESP32 arduino. I want to use the esp-idf framework. Is it possible to install the arduino SDK to be used on the IDF framwork. Thanks in advance for any suggestions or recommendations

I want to install the thingstream arduino sdk made for esp32 on the esp32 idf framework. Is this possible and how?

Comment: you should read the README in detail at https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32 I think it's addressed, or you can read / post issues there

Comment: @vicatcu sorry I think my question is misleading I got the SDK install and working on arduino version for esp. I want to use that same SDK(arduino version) on the esp-IDF so that I am not coding in arduino.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the espressif libraries from ESP-IDF are actually required to be installed as a prerequisite before your arduino setup will be able to do anything with your ESP32 device.

If you have specific questions while following one of the many guides  such as [Arduino Setup for ESP32](http://exploreembedded.com/wiki/Arduino_Setup_for_ESP32) you should put those into a question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can install the Arduino SDK as ESP-IDF component. You can refer to [this](https://espressif-docs.readthedocs-hosted.com/projects/arduino-esp32/en/latest/esp-idf_component.html) document by Espressif on how to setup Arduino as ESP-IDF component.

### Steps to configure Arduino as ESP-IDF component

1. Set FreeRTOS tick rate to 1000Hz in  `menuconfig>Component config>FreeRTOS>Tick rate`
2. Create new folder `components` in your project directory
3. Clone the [Arduino-Esp32](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32) repository in your `components` directory
4. Run `idf.py menuconfig`
5. Build and Flash to Esp32

Note: As of now the Arduino as ESP-IDF component is only compactable with `ESP-IDF v4.4`